# Azure data factory dataflow SELECT DISTINCT

Tags: aggregate-functions, azure-data-factory

I have a dataflow with a few joins and when making the join #5, the number of row goes from 10,000 to 320,000 (to make an example of how the quantity is increased), but after that i have more joins to make so the dataflow is taking longer to complete.

What I do is to add an Aggregate transformation after the joins, to groupby the field that I will use later, using that in a way that I use a SELECT DISTINCT in a query on the database, but still taking soooo long to finish.

How can make this dataflow run faster?

Should I use an Aggregate (and groupby the fields) between every join, to avoid the duplicates or just add the Aggregate (and groupby the fields...) after the join where the  rows starts to increase?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you switch to Lookups instead of Join and then choose "run single row". That provides the SELECT DISTINCT capability in a single step.

Also, to speed up the processing end-to-end, try bumping up to memory optimized and raise the core count.

Comment: Forgot to mention that the source data are flat file in a data lake, using Lookups would work? and about the speed, thats how I am doing it.

Comment: yes, lookup transformation instead of join will work

Comment: Should I choose "match any row", right? and select ANY?

Comment: Any row, first row, or last row, your choice